# Agrh Angular is not working

Tags: angularjs

I cannot seem to pull 
nav.html and footer.html are in include folder

http://www.ultramaticwest.com/sample/

all the files are there

can someone help thanks!

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: are you joking me? This is a good question

    <div ng-include src="'include/footer.html'"></div>  the file is on the server i can open it. index page doesn't see it. How else can i explain?

Comment: Questions should be self contained....we shouldn't have to go off site to review the basics of your issue. That means providing  proper problem description and all relevant code. If you have used the site to solve problems...that's what you saw in all other questions and answers

Comment: I already fixed it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just for the future reference your post is downvoted by so many anonymous people because it does not contain any code at all.

Simply include the files where you need it by doing this

```
<div ng-include src="'pathToYourFooter/nav.html'">

<div ng-include src="'pathToYourFooter/footer.html'">
```